# Comparing bitmaps in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, compare

I have a situation where I have to check if the user profile has changed. I am saving the URL in shared prefs if the shared prefs are empty for the first time. From then on every time I get a URL from intent I am downloading the image from shared preference, downloading the image from the intent and doing the sameAs method. I am wondering if there a better way of doing this? Can anyone suggest to me.

Comment: In general, the correct way to compare 2 files is to hash them both and compare the hashes, rather than to load both into memory.

Better ways of doing the downloading-  check the http headers for the etags data (or worst case last-modified) and avoid having to download it at all.

Comment: You could convert them both to base64 encoding and then do a string compare on the base64 encoded strings...

Answer (score 0):

My suggest  in your situation  not to download Image  , You Just need  to cache it using 
Glide or  Picasso lib

```
Picasso.get()
            .load(finalUrl)
            .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
            .fit()
            .centerInside()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_placeholders)
            .into(target, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                 }

                @Override
                public void onError(Exception e) {
                     Picasso.get()
                            .load(finalUrl1)
                            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_placeholders)
                             .fit()
                             .centerInside()
                             .into(target);
                }
            });
```

so  this check if your Images Is loaded in cache first 
and if exist  do not download it

```
        .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
```

by  this code

and if it not exist in cache  , it will download it